# ValueError when appending dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, valueerror

When I try to interrogate some column values and append that row to another dataframe, I get a ValueError.

Let's say we have two dataframes:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame([['a','Y','name1','5Y'],['b','N','name2','10Y'],['c','N','name3','3Y'],['d','Y', 'name4','10Y']], columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])

df_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
```

Which are:
df_a:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Y | name1 | 5Y |
| b | N | name2 | 10Y |
| c | N | name3 | 3Y |
| d | Y | name4 | 10Y |

df_b:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to interrogate columns c2 and c4 of df_a, so that when c2=Y and c4=10Y to copy that row to df_b.

This is done by using:

```
df_b.append(df_a.loc[(df_a['c2'] == 'Y') and (df_a['c4'] == '10Y')])
```

This returns:
**ValueError:** The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Series boolean comparisons need to be done with `&` not `and`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `df_b.append(df_a.loc[(df_a['c2'] == 'Y') & (df_a['c4'] == '10Y')])`